# Open a link in a new windows

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm using the following code to open the link in a new window, its working in IE8, Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox 6 it's opening in a new tab. How can I fix that?

```
var popupName;
function openPopup(href) {
    popupName = window
            .open(
                    href,
                    'Details',
                    'scrollbars=1,resizable=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,width=700,height=710');
    popupName.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: New tab / new window - who cares?  This is just the browser's implementation

Comment: "Script opening a new window in Opera" ? are you serious ?

Comment: The script opens a non-maximized tab in Opera which has a title bar and close buttons so it really looks like a normal window to most users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266039/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-window/38329689#38329689 see the example there and use window.open() fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the user preferences in the browser itself. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this can not be altered.

Why would you like a new window anyway? Let the user decide (with the browser preferences) if it's a new window or a new tab.. Same effect, less annoyance.

Comment: Thirded.  Next you'll want to install a popup box when they try to leave the page.

Comment: Because the customer want that, new windows, not new tab

Comment: The customer can change his browser preferences to have window.open use a new window instead of a new tab then.

Comment: I think he means the client, not the site customer - but it's your job to explain to the client exactly what this answer has.

Answer (score 1):

If the customer is looking for something that "pops up" on top of other content, you might think of using some dialog framework that employs an IFRAME to load the detail page. For instance, [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) could do the thing (see example "Iframe (75% width and height)" in http://fancybox.net/ front page)

Comment: Yes, mostly I'm using colorbox, but he don't like that, he want a popup widows :).

Comment: sorry, but then the answer is that nowadays the web does not allow the developer to choose how a windows open :(

Answer (score -1):

here is a pretty cool online tool that will generate a link for you http://www.echoecho.com/toolpopupgenerator.htm

I know he is not asking for a generator, but if he generates his code one time and studies it, he will understand how it works

Comment: The OP is not asking for a script builder, OP is asking why it's popping up into a tab instead of a window